# VPN Client Routing

Tags: vpn, routing, router, openvpn, openwrt

I'm having trouble getting my VPN client on open-wrt to work.  The actual VPN connection works fine and I was able to access the remote network from the router but when my VPN is active it shuts down my internet connection.  It appears that it tries to route all traffic over the VPN.  Now I tried using the option "route_noexec" which has th effect that I can't access the remote network anymore. So far I have failed to add the VPN route manually.

This is my VPN client config:

```
config openvpn 'sample_client'
    option client '1'
    option dev 'tun'
    option resolv_retry 'infinite'
    option nobind '1'
    option persist_key '1'
    option persist_tun '1'
    option comp_lzo 'yes'
    option verb '3'
    option remote '*******.com 1194'
    option cipher 'AES-128-CBC'
    option reneg_sec '3600'
    option enabled '1'
    option proto 'tcp'
    option auth 'SHA1'
    option pkcs12 '/lib/uci/upload/cbid.openvpn.sample_client.pkcs12'
    option route_noexec '1'
```

ifconfig tun0:

```
  tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:192.168.254.7  P-t-P:192.168.254.7  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

In addition I set up a VPN interface:

```
config interface 'VPN'
    option ifname 'tun0'
    option _orig_ifname 'tun0'
    option _orig_bridge 'false'
    option proto 'none'

config route
    option interface 'VPN'
    option target '10.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option gateway '192.168.254.1'
```

...and the firewall config:

```
config forwarding
    option dest 'VPN'
    option src 'lan'

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'lan'

config forwarding
    option dest 'lan'
    option src 'VPN'

config forwarding
    option dest 'lan'
    option src 'wan'
```

I believe my main problem is the routing part but I'm not sure to be honest.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:**

I added the route manually now:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.254.1
```

Now I can ping the VPN from the router but the rest of my network still can't access it.

MY routing table looks like this now:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.2.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0         0 eth1
10.0.0.0        192.168.254.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
10.2.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.2.0.1        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.254.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to route clients Internet traffic through the VPN (just to be clear) ?

Comment: krisFR, yes, I only want the remote network to be accessible but I do not want internet traffic to go through the VPN.  The VPN allows doesn't allow that.  So if all traffic goes through the VPN I don't even have internet access anymore.

Comment: Ok. So the below answer is quite good. Don't push the default gateway (0.0.0.0) through your openVPN gateway, but push only routes you need ?

Comment: I tried that and I do have access to the VPN through the router now but not from hosts connected to the router. (see update above)

Comment: Show us the routing table of one of your openvpn clients

Comment: I added my routing table above.  As mentioned the routing works for the router but not for the other devices connected to the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to update the firewall configuration to where it rejects forwarding from LAN to VPN and also enables masquerading and MSS clamping.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do that by using routing table
change the default gateway as you want and just routing the ips you want to the VPN network

I guess this link will help you :
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/

Comment: Thanks Wissam, this seemed to have gotten be a bit closer but it's still not quite where I want it to be. See my update above.